# How to export a collection of Interfaces in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I have a file `actions.ts` that declares a bunch of action types.

actions.ts

```
export interface Action1 extends Action {
type: types.Action1Type
}

export interface Action2 extends Action {
type: types.Action2Type
}

export interface Action3 extends Action {
type: types.Action3Type
}
```

I import these actions in index.ts with:

```
import * as actions from './actions';
```

What is the type of the `actions`variable in the index.ts file?  I would like to be able to create this construct in the actions.ts file itself and export it. Similar to the following:

actions.ts

```
interface Action1 extends Action {
type: types.Action1Type
}

interface Action2 extends Action {
type: types.Action2Type
}

interface Action3 extends Action {
type: types.Action3Type
}

export const Actions = {
  Action1,
  Action2,
  Action3,
}
```

but this gives me an error:

> `Action1` only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces are just type definitions in TypeScript, so you can't make a variable (use them as a value) with actions.

You can use a namespace to combine your actions:

```
namespace Actions {

  export interface Action1 extends Action {
    type: types.Action1Type
  }

  export interface Action2 extends Action {
    type: types.Action2Type
  }

  export interface Action3 extends Action {
    type: types.Action3Type
  }

}
```

This allows you to do the following:

```
import {Actions} from './actions';`
```

But this is basically the same thing as `import * as actions from './actions';`. You cannot use `Actions` as a value.

Comment: I actually tend to include a Union of all the action types in the actions.ts file as well.  FeatureActions = Action1|Action2|Action3;  But import * includes that and I just wanted it as you show. So allowing `namespace` in my tslint rules for this.  It doesn't look to bad actually.  

import { Actions, FeatureAction } from '../../actions';

thx.